# Selenium click dynamic link

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

I have a page structure similar to this:

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <frameset>
        <frame/>
        <frameset id="id1">
            <frame/>
            <frame id="id2">
                <html>
                    <head/>
                    <body class="class1">
                        <form id="id3">
                            <input/>
                            <input/>
                            <input/>
                            <input/>
                            <table/>
                            <table/>
                            <table/>
                            <div id="id4">
                                <div id="id5">
                                    <table id="id6">
                                        <thead/>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr/>
                                            <tr/>
                                            <tr/>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td/>
                                                <td/>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="dynamic link">Text</a>
```

I need to click on the dynamic link - the link and position inside the table varies, but the text is always the same.

I've tried using find_element_by_link_text and it fails.

Using xpath it can not find the form element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to the frame containing the `<a>` element first. Your code would look something like this:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('id3')
driver.find_element_by_link_text('TEXT').click()
```

Note that the above code is only an approximation, since your provided HTML code is only an approximation. In particular, you have a `<frameset>` element as a direct child of another `<frameset>` element, which I believe is invalid HTML. If you indeed have nested framesets, you'll need multiple calls to `switch_to_frame` to navigate down the frame hierarchy until your focus is on the frame containing the document with the element you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can first find all a tags in the page using:
find_elements_by_tag_name

Then iterate over each a tag and check its text since text is always the same

```
a_tags = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for a in a_tags:
    if a.text == 'TEXT':
        a.click()
```

Comment: Still won't work given the above HTML. The link being sought is inside a frame, and even `find_elements_by_tag_name` won't find the elements in a child frame's document.